# git - get result change from several non consequent commits

Tags: git, git-commit

Let's say I have the following history in my git repo:

```
C (master)
x (origin/master)
B
x
A
x
```

A, B and C are commits that I am interested in, while x are some other changes (may be more than 1 commit). I would like to know what result change was performed by commits A, B and C ignoring any other changes that were done by other commits in between.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rebase these changes to create one commit of them:

```
git rebase -i A^ // QWE^ means parent of QWE
```

In interactive reabse you can change order of commits for your C,B,A to be on top. You can also set B and A to "squash" or "fix" so these commits will be visible as one commit.

After that if you want to see changes made by commit A+B+C you can simply:

```
git log -p -1 A+B+C // -p means show diff, -1 means show just 1 commit
```

The problem is that during rebase you may have to do some merges.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to do a code review of the changes in `A-B-C`.

I recommend to first checkout `C` in detached HEAD state and than do a rebase interactive.

```
git checkout --detach C
git rebase -i A^
```

The rebase interactive editor will show you something like this

```
pick A
pick x
pick B
pick x
pick C
```

Remove the `x` lines and squash the other commits. E.g.

```
pick A
squash B
squash C
```

After the rebase finished your HEAD points to a commit that only contains the changes of `A-B-C`.

You can see the changes using

```
git show HEAD
```

But keep in mind that you might get conflicts that you must resolve. This can happen if e.g. commit `C` depends on changes introduced in one of the `x` commits that you removed. The same for commit 'B'.